# Has the gift notification been removed from the game?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

The game used to display a permanent gift notification (domain names are censored)  during warmup:

[image: gift notification]

The menu obstructed vision and as you can see it was widely used for spam. Has this notification now been removed entirely from the game?

Answer (score 2):

It was indeed [removed](http://counterstrike.wikia.com/wiki/Gift_Packages), reason is as followed

> The notification HUD was removed because people used it to promote their websites (Mostly skin gambling sites) by putting the link in their username.

Comment: Wikia is not a reliable source unfortunately — if you can add link to the official patch notes I will accept your answer for sure.